# Generating curve25519 Curve Key Pair with bcrypt in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, bcrypt

I have following code to generate curve25519 Key Pair. But when I am exporting the keys, size is not matching expected key size. What is wrong with the implementation? Documentation states the following:

"
BCRYPT_ECCPUBLIC_BLOB
Export an ECC public key. The pbOutput buffer receives a BCRYPT_ECCKEY_BLOB structure immediately followed by the key data."

Also, why curve25519 key size in Windows (based on documentation) is 255 and not 256, as it should be?

The output of the following code is:

```
Key size 72
Struct size 8
```

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <bcrypt.h>


#ifndef NT_SUCCESS
#define NT_SUCCESS(Status) ((NTSTATUS)(Status) >= 0)
#endif

#pragma comment (lib, "bcrypt.lib")

int main()
{
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = NULL;
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE alg;
    ULONG cbBuffer = 0;
    PCRYPT_PROVIDERS pBuffer = NULL;
    NTSTATUS status;
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithm;

    
    status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlgorithm, BCRYPT_ECDH_ALGORITHM, MS_PRIMITIVE_PROVIDER, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        printf("BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider failed with code 0x%08x\n", status);
        return status;
    }
    status = BCryptSetProperty(hAlgorithm, BCRYPT_ECC_CURVE_NAME, (PUCHAR)BCRYPT_ECC_CURVE_25519, sizeof(BCRYPT_ECC_CURVE_25519),0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        printf("BCryptSetProperty failed with code 0x%08x\n", status);

        return status;
    }
    status = BCryptGenerateKeyPair(hAlgorithm, &hKey, 255, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        printf("BCryptGenerateKeyPair failed with code 0x%08x\n", status);

        return status;
    }

    status = BCryptFinalizeKeyPair(hKey, 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        printf("BCryptFinalizeKeyPair failed with code 0x%08x\n", status);
        return status;
    }
    PUCHAR publicKey;
    ULONG publicKeySize;

    status = BCryptExportKey(hKey, NULL,
        BCRYPT_ECCPUBLIC_BLOB, NULL, 0, &publicKeySize, 0);
    printf("Key size %lu \n", publicKeySize);
    printf("Struct size %lu \n", sizeof(BCRYPT_ECCKEY_BLOB));
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        printf("BCryptExportKey failed with code 0x%08x\n", status);
        return status;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *key size* or *key length* is a specific value that represents the size of the value that determines the strength of the key. In this case, for curve25519 that's actually 255 bits (the prime field is 2^255 - 19, hence the name, and we don't hold the -19 against it). Generally we don't care about the single bit difference with 256 either and the private key value is 256 bits / 32 bytes in size, so whatever.

However, that doesn't mean that the encoding of the keys will be that size. This makes sense as you can encode a key in many ways. With `BCRYPT_ECCKEY_BLOB` you'll actually get a Microsoft proprietary structure back (because Microsoft didn't care that much when it comes to standardizing cryptography).

In this case it will consist of:

- a 4 byte magic that includes the 4 byte magic specific to ECC / Curve25519;
- 4 bytes that determine the length of the structure that follows;
- and then the X and Y coordinates of the uncompressed public key **point**, 2 * 32 bytes = 64 bytes.

4 + 4 + 64 is 72.

Now the `sizeof` simply shows you the size of the 64 bit structure without the X and Y coordinates, as that is how the struct is defined. That's however **not** the full public key as it is exported.

In general you have key strength is smaller or equal to key size, which is smaller or equal to key encoding. For symmetric keys these are generally the same (if we don't go into quantum computing attacks) although even an AES key can of course be encoded using a structure with meta data. Asymmetric keys generally consist of more values, and are generally (much) larger.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a api provided by microsoft to convert X,Y ECC coordinates to actual 256 bits PK?

Comment: If there is then I don't see it either unfortunately. And I've certainly looked!

Comment: @Farseer Thanks for the accept. Would fully support a followup question asking for converting the Microsoft defined BLOB containing an uncompressed point into a curve25519 public key with just the Y-coordinate and a sign indicator for the X-coordinate.

Comment: Note that this is in [RFC 8032](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032#section-5.1.5) : " The public key A is the encoding of the point [s]B.  First, encode the y-coordinate (in the range 0 <= y < p) as a little-endian string of 32 octets.  The most significant bit of the final octet is always zero. To form the encoding of the point [s]B, copy the least significant bit of the x coordinate to the most significant bit of the final octet. The result is the public key." Note that Ed25519 assumes signature generation / verification, not key agreement, and beware that most libs will use big endian!

Comment: Converting back to x, y is harder, but there is a routine in the bottom of the RFC.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will extract public/private keys:

```
ULONG Bytes;

struct
    {
        BCRYPT_ECCKEY_BLOB Header;
        BYTE X[32]; // This is Public Key of Curve25519
        BYTE Y[32]; // This could be ignored
        BYTE d[32]; // This is Private key of Curve25519
    } BcryptKeyPair;
    

    

    Status = BCryptExportKey(Key, NULL, BCRYPT_ECCPRIVATE_BLOB, (PUCHAR)&BcryptKeyPair,  sizeof(BcryptKeyPair), &Bytes, 0);
```